# Laravel: throttle /register

Tags: laravel, middleware, throttling

Last night we got over 2000+ new created users via script. Due to this I want to throttle the register process to up to 10 registerations per minute. I added the following code (for testing I chose 2 per 2 minutes, to reach the limit faster):

```
Route::post('register', ['uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@register'])->middleware('throttle:2,2')->name('register.send');
```

**For some reason the request always says X-RateLimit-Remaining is 1. So he decreases from 2 to 1, but never goes further down. IT IS ALWAYS 1, even after multiple posts!!!**

I found out the response of post to /register is a Code 302 (Found) - may this be a reason? Normal get requests seems to throttle fine, but when I throttle post: /register it stays 1 as described above.

Could be helpful:
[image: Response details]

Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe your throttle settings in ```Kernel.php``` are overriding your middleware on the route. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#middleware-groups)

Comment: Any idea how I can check this? But why would it stay at "1 left" then? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Going into the file and looking if it has the throttling middleware enabled (as explained in the docs)

Comment: They can be found there just as in the docuemntation (since I did not change the Kernel at any time) - is this a problem? Sorry if this is noob

Comment: Just comment it out and see if it solves your problem... don't worry about being a noob. Not having enough noobs is the biggest problem in software development ;)

Comment: So I commented out the "throttle:60,1" line in the api section - sadly this did not help (or I was looking at the wrong line?). I still have n-1 attempts left every time. PS: When I enter an already used email I get an error-message and Code 200 - in this case the throttle works normally! But when I enter a new mail, I get code 302 and the "always remaining n-1"

Comment: Because you set 2 calls per 2 minutes you get 1 remaining. If you do 1 per 1 minute (which is essentially the same), you will get the result you expect I think. Otherwise I think your question needs more detail for me to understand your problem.

Comment: When I set to 1 the remaining tries will !always! be 0... it counts n-1 but never more. So even with "throttle:1,1" I can send unlimited register requests :( He will say 0 left, but this will not stop me from spamming.